# How to create WordPress Posts from Facebook feed?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a client that would like to take the pictures from their Facebook fan page and import each picture into WordPress as a separate post.  I am relatively new to WordPress and PHP, so I am not sure how to do this.  Is there a plugin that already does this or do I have to code it myself?

I have created a Facebook app and can get the pictures through the Graph API.  But, I'm not sure how to make them into posts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to iterate the data and wp function wp_insert_post();

For e.g.

```
$postarr = array('post_status' => 'draft', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_author' => $user_ID,
 'ping_status' => get_option('default_ping_status'), 'post_parent' => 0,
 'menu_order' => 0, 'to_ping' =>  '', 'pinged' => '', 'post_password' => '',
 'guid' => '', 'post_content_filtered' => '', 'post_excerpt' => '', 'import_id' => 0,
'post_content' => '', 'post_title' => '');

wp_insert_post($postarr);
```